# How to replace text surrounded with stars with bolded text in my message

Tags: java, android, text, formatting, logic

I am making a chat app and I want to add a feature which if the user types text between two stars (*) , the text between the two stars **bold**.

For example if the user types the messages as `*this is bold* and this is not`,the message between stars is bold and the message outside if not bold.

I am unable to get the logic to do it. The code I have currently written is :

```java
    String[] boldChecker = chatMessage.message.split("\\*");
                for (int i = 0; boldChecker.length > i ; i++){
                    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                        //is even and not bold
                        Log.d("boldArea - No",boldChecker[i]);
                    } else {
                        //is odd and bold
                        Log.d("boldArea - Yes",boldChecker[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Here `chatmessage.message` is the message typed by the user. The only thing I know is that to set the text to bold, I need to use `html.fromHtml(<b>bold text</b>)`.

Comment: Please try to use regex , this is for Java SE8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### You can proceed with this approach:

Simply replace pairs of * with `<b> </b>` tags and then use `Html.fromHtml(message)` to make the message bold wherever user typed the message between pair of *

Like this:
let message = "*This is bold* and this is not *"
then change message = "<b>This is bold</b> and this is not *"

**You can use this code for replacement**

```java
        // Let the message typed by the user is this
        String msg = "Hello friends, *This is the bold text* and this is not but *this is also bold* ** *";

        /**
         * @params firstIndex = index of the first * of the pair we are looking in the msg string
         *         secondIndex = index of the second * of the pair
         *         pairCount = to help us acknowledge that the pair *, we are looking for, is ready
         */
        int firstIndex = 0, secondIndex = 0, pairCount = 0;

        int i = 0;
        while (true){

            char c = msg.charAt(i);

            if (c == '*'){
                if (pairCount == 0) {
                    pairCount += 1;
                    firstIndex = i;
                }
                else if (pairCount == 1) {
                    pairCount += 1;
                    secondIndex = i;
                }
            }

            if (pairCount == 2){

                // replacing first * with <b>
                msg = msg.substring(0,firstIndex) + "<b>" + msg.substring(firstIndex+1);


                // replacing second * with </b>
                // increasing secondIndex by 2
                // because length of "msg" is increased by 2
                // after replacing <b> with *
                secondIndex += 2;
                msg = msg.substring(0,secondIndex) + "</b>" + msg.substring(secondIndex+1);


                // changing pair count to 0 as we have replaced the * pair
                // and are looking for new pair
                pairCount = 0;


                // Increasing i value to 5 because we have added <b> and </b> (total length = 7)
                // on replacement of * pairs (total length = 2)
                // 7 - 2 = 5
                i += 5;

            }

            i += 1;

            if (i >= msg.length()) break;
        }


        // Set the text to the TextView using Html 
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

**Result**
[image: bold text example]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) to bold the **starred** parts of text.

**Here is the procedure:**

1. Create a regex to get the text surrounded between two stars.

   Here it is: `"\\*(.*?)\\*"`
2. Get the matcher on your message text that matches the regex from step 1

   `Pattern.compile("\\*(.*?)\\*").matcher(text)`
3. Iterate over the matcher and use [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) to bold the matched groups; but the problem that you need to remove the starts before adding the spans, and this will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you usede the matcher indices; so, we'll add a counter that counts for every start, and decrease the matcher indices by this counter.
4. Set the bold spans using [`setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int))

**The code is demonstrated comments:**

```
private Matcher getMatchedStars(String text) {
    // matching start & end stars with a regex
    return Pattern.compile("\\*(.*?)\\*").matcher(text);
}

private Spannable getBolded(String text, Matcher matcher) {

    // Remove the starts from the text
    String noStarText = text.replace("*", "");

    // Create the Spannable from the no start text
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(noStarText);

    // count represents the current no. of removed stars
    int count = 1;

    // Iterate over the matched bolded text
    while (matcher.find()) {
        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD),
                matcher.start() - count, // remove all previous stars from the start index
                matcher.end() - count - 1, // remove all previous stars from the end index
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        count += 2; // Add 2 to remove 2 stars from the current iteration (i.e. a complete bolded text is finished)
    }
    return spannable;
}
```

**Testing:**

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
String text = "Hello *Java* But here is *Android*, \n wait it's *Kotlin*";
Spannable spannable = getBolded(text, getMatchedStars(text));
tv.setText(spannable);
```

[image]

Comment: There are two issues which need to be fixed. count represents the current no. of removed stars needs to be 0 at the beginning. matcher.end() - count - 1 is also wrong, because you then need to substract 2 stars.

Answer (score 0):

There are further problems in @Hritik's solution.

1. Tab chars and next line chars are ignored in the above solution, which I fixed using the following

   msg.toString().replace("\n","
   ")
   .replace("\t"," ").replace(" "," ")
2. It is breaking words. For example, it is showing StackOverflow as stac
   overflow.
   Any idea how to fix word break in HTML.fromHtml()?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32095316)